# Can I add custom time-based data to a video file output by AVCaptureSession/AVCaptureMovieFileOutput?

Tags: ios, avfoundation, avcapturesession

I am using AVCaptureSession and AVCaptureMovieFileOutput to capture video/audio from a camera and write it to a mov file.

I am also capturing time-based data from another source (let's say accelerometer samples) that I want to keep in sync with the AV capture timeline.

Is it possible to add a third "media" track to the mov file containing my custom time-based data?

Alternatively, AVMetadataItem has a time property, so could I add my data as time-based metadata to the mov file or one of its media tracks? Is it possible to add an AVAssetTrack of mediaType AVMediaTypeTimedMetadata to hold the timed data ?

Comment: Apple's sample code includes a demo showing new facilities in iOS 9 for recording timed metadata into a movie file.